# How do I verify that two series of a pandas dataFrame have the same elements?

Tags: python, pandas, compare, series

I wish to compare two series in a dataFrame, and get a boolean True or False answer as to whether they have exactly the same elements.

If an element differs, then I'd like to know its index number.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add any example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow.. My code is posted below, (the second Answer from the top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use `isin`:

```
In [123]:
s1 = pd.Series(np.arange(5))
s2 = pd.Series(np.arange(1,6))
s2

Out[123]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int32

In [125]:    
s1.isin(s2)

Out[125]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

From the above you can get the index values that are `False` by negating the mask using `~`:

```
In [127]:
s1[~s1.isin(s2)].index

Out[127]:
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

EdChum, thanks for your answer!

It's better than the one I have managed to work out, which I will post below anyway:

```
ser1 = Series(np.arange(16))
arr = ser1.reshape(4,4)
df = DataFrame((arr),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
ser_e = Series([2,6,10,14])
df['e'] = ser_e

df['c']>df['b']
df.loc[df['c'] != df['e'] ]
```